# How do I stop animation from starting at the same starting point as the 1st one and continue smoothly from after 1st one?

Tags: animation, mixamo

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to animate a girl walking. I downloaded two Mixamo files and found a YouTube tutorial to join them together using Blender's Non-Linear Animation editor.

[image: The Girl I'm trying to animate by mixing 2 mixamo animations]

When I play the animation, the first one plays and goes back to the starting point.

[image: the first animation's position on the non linear editor timeline]

The second one does not start from the last frame of the first one but goes to the very first frame to start.

[image: the starting point of the first animation]

This does not show in the timeline. The timeline makes it look like it is playing smoothly from the first animation to the next.

I tried blending the 2 animations but it doesn't seem to fix the second one flying back to the beginning to begin. Please how can I make the 2 animations play smoothly without the 2nd one jumping back to the beginning of the first one?

Comment: That's explained in [this](https://youtu.be/fLfjHzJy2A0) YT tutorial from around [5:33](https://youtu.be/fLfjHzJy2A0?t=332).

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I also found some other cool things in the video too. Thank you @JohnEason